# I am working on eclipse web dynamic project. Using Spring MVC. For some reason, I have to load a xml file using

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, file-io, web-applications

I am using eclipse's web dynamic project. I am using a library which is taking an xml file as input for its configuration. It is using the following code to load the xml file.

```
URL url = Resource.class.getClassLoader().getResource(filename);
```

I can't change the code in library. I need to pass this filename as String to it. Where should I keep the file(fastAlgo.xml), How should I give the path in string? My project structure is the following -

```
Project -
  -deployment descriptor
  -Java resources
   -target
   -WebContent
      -META-INF
      -WEB-INF
      -fastalgo.xml
```

Comment: did you try WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib ?  i think these are under default class path of web application.

Comment: If you want to load it as a resource it needs to be on the classpath. If you want to load it as a file *internal* to the web app then you need to use `getRealPath`. If you want to load it as a file *external* to the web app then you just need to provide an absolute pathname.

Comment: @DaveNewton I need it as internal, i.e just want to load for internal algorithm once. This file is static as well, will not change while project is running. But i don't have the option of using anything other then getResource as i can't make changes in library.

Comment: Then put the file on the classpath, like I said.

Comment: @DaveNewton It worked. Thanks a lot. Can you please explain why it worked like this?

Comment: @Jimmy Yes I tried it, but it din't worked.

Comment: Because that's how resource loading works; resources have to be on the classpath.